# new programmer here,whats wrong with this stack program?

Tags: c, struct

when i execute it the function do not work why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack{

int x[10];

int last;
};

void init(struct stack *s)
{

    s->last=0;
}

 void insert(struct stack *s)
    {
        int a;

        while(a!=0)
        {
        int i;
        printf("Enter the value\n");

        scanf("%d",&i);

        s->last++;

        s->x[s->last]=i;
        printf("%d",s->x[s->last]);
        printf("enter 1 to continue 0 to exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);

    }
    }

int main()
{

    struct stack s;

    int y,z;

    printf("Trying out stacks\n");

    printf("\n______________\n");

    init(s);

    insert(s);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you think this code works?  What indication do you have of this?  *Describe the problem.*

Comment: `int a;` --> `int a=1;`, `s->last=0;` --> `s->last=-1;`, `init(s);` --> `init(&s);`, `insert(s);` --> `insert(&s);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `insert()`, you declared

```
int a;
```

and then without initializing `a` you are doing the following,

```
while(a!=0)
```

will give [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The following lines can leads buffer overflow,

```
s->last++; 
s->x[s->last]=i; // no restriction applied on last
```

`last` can be more than `9` which can cause buffer overflow as `x[10]`.